# Unwanted left-right rotation in run animation imported from Mixamo

Tags: unity, animation

A humanoid run animation I downloaded from Mixamo is working fine on their site and in Blender.

When I import it into Unity it shows a strange movement: [the full body is rotating left & right in a strange way when animation is running](https://streamable.com/2g0mc).

[image: Animated gif excerpt from the linked video]

Here are my import settings for the animation:

[image: Unity Animation inspector]

Comment: In future, I recommend using a screen recording tool like LICEcap rather than taking a cellphone video of your screen.

Comment: Thank you for edit my question and I will try this program next time. Do you have any clue for this issue ?

Comment: If I did, I'd post it as an answer. You don't need to solicit help from individual users on this site. Your question post alone is sufficient to invite answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read about this before and I think you need to fix the rotation manually.
[Root Motion - how it works](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/RootMotion.html)

> Bake into Pose: The orientation will stay on the body transform (or Pose). The Root Orientation will be constant and delta Orientation will be identity. This means that the Game Object will not be rotated at all by that AnimationClip.
>
> Only AnimationClips that have similar start and stop Root Orientation should use this option. You will have a Green Light in the UI
>    telling you that an AnimationClip is a good candidate. A suitable candidate would be a straight walk or a run.
>
> Based Upon: This lets you set the orientation of the clip. Using Body Orientation, the clip will be oriented to follow the forward vector of body. This default setting works well for most Motion Capture (Mocap) data like walks, runs, and jumps, but it will fail with motion like strafing where the motion is perpendicular to the body’s forward vector. In those cases you can manually adjust the orientation using the Offset setting. Finally you have Original that will automatically add the authored offset found in the imported clip. It is usually used with Keyframed data to respect orientation that was set by the artist.
>
> Offset: used to enter the offset when that option is chosen for Based Upon.

So, I think you have to deal with "Root Transform Rotation" only. Bake into Pose,Checked. Change Based Upon to "Body Orientation". for Offset, put a value that makes your doll facing the small blue arrow direction. Plus, try to Unchecked "Apply Root Motion" option in your Animator.